# What's the difference between finite clause and infinite clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

What does **infinite clause** mean and which features differentiate it from **finite clause**?
I know so far that **finite clause** is inflectable while **infinite clause** is uninflectable. But I need some examples to explain this theory to me.

And what is the role of complement here? Is **infinite clause** always a complement of the **finite clause**?

Comment: You mean non-finite. It's a big topic. What research have you done? There is a huge amount of information on the Internet about this topic. Have you looked? Here's just one: [link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/finite.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A finite clause is one with a tensed verb.

> He *woke up* <sup>tensed</sup> early.

A non-finite clause is one with an infinitive or participle, which are tenseless, and therefore not on a time-line. Non-finite clauses often serve as a nominal grammatical subject.

> *To wake up* <sup>infinitival</sup> after a night of carousing can be difficult.